# kotlin: check if item is textbox

Tags: android, kotlin, button, textview

i'm trying to check if an Element is an TextBox in kotlin. I've a list which contains the following 4 items:

```
0 = {AppCompatTextView@9533} "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView{4df7f9e V.ED..... ........ 0,0-47,111 #7f07007f app:id/roller1}"
1 = {AppCompatTextView@9554} "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView{e3faa7f V.ED..... ........ 0,111-47,222 #7f070080 app:id/roller2}"
2 = {AppCompatTextView@9555} "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView{4487a4c V.ED..... ........ 0,222-47,333 #7f070081 app:id/roller3}"
3 = {AppCompatButton@9531} "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton{193bc20 VFED..C.. ...P.... 406,333-673,465 #7f07007e app:id/roll_button}"
```

Now I'm trying to check if each of those items is a TextView with this expression:
`if (item is TextView){ rollRoller(item) }`. But for some reason, the condition is true for all items. Could anyone please explaine me why? Thanks!

Comment: Becasue `public class Button extends TextView` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 0):

As the [IR42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12191177/ir42) said - Button extends TextView.

Hierarchy of `AppCompatButton` super classes:

[image: Hierarchy of super classes of AppCompatButton]

Instead of checking for `is TextView` you can use or `is AppCompatTextView`. But such change will require you to use `AppCompatTextView` in your layouts whose views you check.

There is one known subclass of [`AppCompatTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatTextView) - [`EmojiAppCompatTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/emoji/widget/EmojiAppCompatTextView.html). Thus, it will be a lot safer for you.

Comment: Many thanks! But what do you guys think about another expression like `if (item !is Button)`?

Comment: You can get a lot of not-text-view results. It actually depends on what is it that you are trying to do.